# not using free data allowance

Tags: data

I have a 5Gig data allowance on my phone and I hardly ever use more than a fraction of it.  But I seem to be paying a lot through my broadband provider.  How can I persuade my phone to use my free data allowance?!
It's an iphone and I have a vodafone plan.

Answer (score 3):

To turn cellular data on or off, go to Settings, then tap Cellular or Mobile Data. If you're using an iPad, you might see **Settings** > **Cellular Data**.

An iPhone screen showing cellular data settings

Depending on your carrier and device, you might have additional options listed under Cellular Data Options:

- **Enable LTE, 4G, or 3G**: You can select what type of network connection to use for voice and data. Learn more about these options. Learn about data options with 5G on your iPhone or iPad.
- **Turn Voice Roaming on or off**: With CDMA networks, you can turn off Voice Roaming to avoid charges from using other carriers' networks.
- **Turn Data Roaming on or off**: When you're traveling internationally, you can turn off data roaming to avoid roaming charges. If you have an international data plan, you may need to keep Data Roaming on.

The Apple Support article "[Use cellular data on your iPhone or iPad](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201299)" should help and provide additional context.

Answer (score 1):

To use cellular data, disable Wi-Fi. This may impact location services.